# How can i create combo box for date selection in html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a combo box for date selection in my web page.there should three box for day,month, year respectively and users just select from the given items.

Comment: cn u share the code have u tried so far ?

Comment: i think you need to open this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp or you can use this plugin https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: This ends up being a library recommendation question, which is off-topic for SO. HTML doesn't have comboboxes, just text inputs and select boxes. To do a combo box, you have to write **significant** amounts of code or use a combobox library. But it sounds like you want a datepicker, not a combobox.

Comment: you can make custom dropdown options with `<select>` and `<option>` , but this is a lot of work where you could just use a datepicker. But if you really want a custom dropdown, you need to keep in mind that the days are dependant on the months and years (leap years) for example you can have (30,31,28,29)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using HTML5 input type="date".

```
<input type="date">
```